# Wordpress: change language after install

Tags: php, wordpress

I accidentally installed a Hebrew version of the latest wordpress and started developing on it, my client asked me to change it to English, so no problem, I go to Settings and change the language to English, all my admin panel is now in English.

The problem is that the error messages or blog sidebars are still in Hebrew, just an example to illustrate the problem:

The site language in the settings is set to English, if you create a contact form using <kbd>Contact Form 7</kbd> plugin, add it to a page and click "Submit" the error message comes out in Hebrew still, how can I force wordpress to not use the Hebrew translations anymore?

**What have I tried?**

I have tried to upload `en_GB` translation files to `/languages` folder, even to sub-directories just to be sure:
[image]

Then I try the contact form in Chrome (incognito):
[image]

Added `define ('WPLANG', 'en_GB');` to `wp-config.php`... nada.

And... No! I do not have plugins running such as `WPML` or `Polylang` that translate my website. I am using the latest version of Wordpress (4.3) with [Total Wordpress Theme](http://themeforest.net/item/total-responsive-multipurpose-wordpress-theme/6339019)

Sidenote: Wordpress says this: `Note: The WPLANG constant in your wp-config.php file is no longer needed.` so there's no point in setting that value in `wp-config.php` as I understand.

**FIXED IT!** Just need to set <kbd>Contact Form 7</kbd> language to English :)

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the issue is due to the language that you chose to create the contact form. Note that `Contact Form 7` plugin supports multiple languages. When you add a new contact form, it asks you the language preference for that particular form.

As for the Hebrew text in your sidebar, check the `Widgets` page in the admin panel. You could be using the Text Widget to embed raw text into the site.

Also, with the recent versions of WordPress, there's no need to edit the `wp-config.php` file and add the `WPLANG` constant anymore.

Comment: Aha! that was it! you're right, it's only the contact form problem. Thanks.

Comment: Glad I could help you. :)

Answer (score 1):

Download the `.mo` language files from:

https://make.wordpress.org/polyglots/teams/

Create a folder in:

`/wp-content` directory called `/languages`.

In your wp-config.php add the following:

`define ('WPLANG', 'en_GB');`

Upload the MO files for the english language to that folder.

That's it.

Comment: I understand your logic, I guess the wordpress installation really did miss the translation files but when I uploaded them and followed your instructions it didn't work. I have revised my answer with what I've tried.

Comment: It was only contact form 7 translation. Fixed. Thanks mate.